# drop point in training error and validation error figure

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have seen these following kind of figures on some papers related to validation error and training error.

Why do all figures have sudden drop point? For instance here, it dramatically decreased at Epoch 40.

[image: validation error]

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons. You may want to provide more info, such as the detail of their approach. One of the most common reasons is that the learning rate is changed at Epoch 40.